# Is it possible to update an already created job in Kue Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, queue, kue

I am creating jobs using [Kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue).

```
jobs.create('myQueue', { 'title':'test', 'job_id': id ,'params':  params } )
            .delay(milliseconds)
            .removeOnComplete( true )
            .save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log( 'jobs.create.err', err );
                }

});
```

Every job has a delay time, and normally it is 3 hours.

Now I will to check every incoming request that wants to create a new job and get the id .

As you can see from the above code, when I am creating a job I will add the job id to the job.

So now I want to check the incoming id with the existing jobs' job_id s in the queue and update that existing job with the new parameters if a matching id
found.

So my job queue will have unique job_id every time :).

Is it possible? I have searched a lot, but no help found. I checked the kue [JSON API](https://github.com/Automattic/kue#json-api). but it only can create and get retrieve jobs, can not update existing records.

Comment: Have you tried the update method ? https://github.com/Automattic/kue/blob/master/lib/queue/job.js#L807

Comment: Use the json API to GET /job/<id> before creating the job. If it exists (status 200), update the job. If it doesn't exist (status 404), create the job.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not mentioned in the documentation and examples, but there is an [update](https://github.com/Automattic/kue/blob/master/lib/queue/job.js#L807) method for a `job`.

You can update your jobs by `job_id` this way:

```
// you have the job_id
var job_id_to_update = 1;
// get delayed jobs
jobs.delayed( function( err, ids ) {
  ids.forEach( function( id ) {
    kue.Job.get( id, function( err, job ) {
      // check if this is job we want
      if (job.data.job_id === job_id_to_update) {
          // change job properties
          job.data.title = 'set another title';
          // save changes
          job.update();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The full example is [here](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/master/nodejs-kue-test/server.js).

Update: you can also consider using the "native" job ID, which is known for kue.
You can get the job id when you create the job:

```
var myjob = jobs.create('myQueue', ...
    .save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log( 'jobs.create.err', err );
        }
        var job_id = myjob.id;
        // you can send job_id back to the client
});
```

Now you can directly modify the job without looping over the list:

```
kue.Job.get( id, function( err, job ) {
  // change job properties
  job.data.title = 'set another title';
  // save changes
  job.update();
});
```

Comment: does it update 'delay' period? below is my code, before and after the update, delay remains the same

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to post an update. This ticket https://github.com/Automattic/kue/issues/505 has the answer for my question.